# How to generate a child node in Firebase Real time data base in react native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am uploading some data in react native firebase database.i have to add an array of data in it with separate node. i am not understanding how to perform it. here is my code...

```
firebase.database().ref('Shops/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).push({
  UserName: this.state.Uname,
  name:this.state.Name,
  tagline:this.state.TagLine,
  description:this.state.Description,
  number:this.state.number,
  image_url_logo:this.state.base64_datalogo,
  image_url_banner:this.state.base64_data,

})
```

i want to generate another node in it with name of `products`. and it is an array .
Just want to know how to generate array with a child node in this structure please guide.

[image]

Here is what i actually want.

Comment: Some quick-fire questions for missing info (to edit into the question): The above code doesn't mention "products" - what have you tried already? What is in the array of data? Does it really need to be an array rather than an id->value table? Where is "products" located? What do you mean by "child node in this structure"? Do you mean that this array is under `Shops/{userId}`? Is it private to this shop or shared across the platform?

Comment: The Firebase Blog has an article on [best practices for arrays](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) that you should also consider looking at.

Comment: @samthecodingman products is array of data .... i want to add array with all that data in another node called products.

Comment: Why not use `firebase.database().ref('Products').push({ /* new product data */ })`?

Comment: can i use it bellow this line image_url_banner:this.state.base64_data, ??? @samthecodingman

Comment: It depends. It could be that simple (as long as it's not inside the `.push({...})`), but without answers to the questions above it could be the wrong approach. Please take the time to answer and edit in that information first.

Comment: @samthecodingman , please check i have added what i actually want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this use case, it is as simple as nesting the array under the data you push to the server.

```js
firebase.database().ref('Shops/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).push({
  UserName: this.state.Uname,
  name:this.state.Name,
  tagline:this.state.TagLine,
  description:this.state.Description,
  number:this.state.number,
  image_url_logo:this.state.base64_datalogo,
  image_url_banner:this.state.base64_data,
  products: [
    {
      name: 'rubber duck',
      price: '5',
      ...
    },
    {
      name: 'kitchen sink',
      price: '200',
      ...
    }
  ]
})
```

However, an issue arises when you wish to list all your shops on a page. If you wanted to grab the name, tagline, description, contact number and image of each shop, you would have to download the data for every item that store sells even if you don't use it.

Instead consider splitting out a store's products into a separate database location.

```js
let shopRef = firebase.database().ref('Shops/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).push();
let shopId = shopRef.key; // unique shop ID

let setShopDataPromise = shopRef.set({
  UserName: this.state.Uname,
  name:this.state.Name,
  tagline:this.state.TagLine,
  description:this.state.Description,
  number:this.state.number,
  image_url_logo:this.state.base64_datalogo,
  image_url_banner:this.state.base64_data,
});

let setShopItemsPromise = firebase.database().ref('ShopItems/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + '/' + shopId).set([
    {
      name: 'rubber duck',
      price: '5',
      ...
    },
    {
      name: 'kitchen sink',
      price: '200',
      ...
    }
]);

Promise.all([setShopDataPromise, setShopItemsPromise])
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Shop uploaded successfully');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // something went wrong
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Now as arrays are [best avoided in Realtime Databases](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html), I would run your `products` array through the following function before passing them to set to give each item it's [own unique product ID](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html). The products will still be uploaded in the same order but will make management easier.

```js
function arrayToKeyPairs(arr) {
  let rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
  let newKey = () => rootRef.push().key;
  return arr.reduce((acc, v) => {
    acc[newKey()] = v
    return acc;
  }, {});
}
```

Comment: How you are generating the shopId here.?

Comment: Ah sorry that was a typo from before I renamed `createStorePushPromise` to `setShopDataPromise` and then reordered my code. These are just the name I gave the Promise returned by `.push()` and `.set()` used to manage the asynchronous operations. When you call `.push()` without any arguments, it [creates the database reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data) to the new database location without uploading any data. You can then use the `ref.key` property to get the new Push ID which I save as the variable `shopId`.